# Microsoft Graph API - Update password - Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to update a user via Microsoft Graph API, I am able to update the `DisplayName` but the `PasswordProfile` I get an error:

```
Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

Here are the roles associated to the token when I decoded the JWT token at http://jwt.io :

```js
"roles": [
    "User.ReadWrite.All",
    "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
    "Group.ReadWrite.All"
],
```

Based on [the documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference) it seems these permissions should suffice.

Here is my code (taken from a console app), I was able to figure out the call is failing via Fiddler, the `UpdateAsync` does not throw an exception.

```cs
try
{
    var userId = "9a5413cd-85ff-4ad1-ab2f-b443941abd8e";
    var token = GetToken().Result;
    System.Console.Write($"Token: {token}");

    var newPassword = "TwDx5zgHxe51DZZ";
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = GetAuthenticatedClient(token);

    // This works -- Updating Display name
    graphClient.Users[userId].Request().UpdateAsync(new User
    {
        DisplayName = "NewDisplayName"
    });

    // This does not work - Updating password
    graphClient.Users[userId].Request().UpdateAsync(new User
    {
        PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
        {
            Password = newPassword,
                ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true
        }
    });
    System.Console.WriteLine("---Update Complete---");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Method for getting token:

```cs
public async Task<string> GetToken()
{
    //  Constants
    var tenant = "dev-mytenantmydomaincom";
    var resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/";
    var clientID = "XXXXXXXX-87ef-494d-b921-cf8956006b0e";
    var secret = "zgkzas2THJLiD5XXXXXX";

    //  Ceremony
    var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}";
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
    var credentials = new ClientCredential(clientID, secret);
    var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credentials);
    return authResult.AccessToken;
}
```

Here is the full response via Fiddler:

```js
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
request-id: 6edcf194-7705-4cd7-8144-767925cc9ee4
client-request-id: 6edcf194-7705-4cd7-8144-767925cc9ee4
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"East US","Slice":"SliceB","ScaleUnit":"001","Host":"AGSFE_IN_27","ADSiteName":"EST"}}
Duration: 69.2849
Date: Thu, 31 Aug 2017 13:15:34 GMT

{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
            "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
                "innerError": {
            "request-id": "6edcf194-7705-4cd7-8144-767925cc9ee4",
                "date": "2017-08-31T13:15:34"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Passwords are a particularly sensitive data set and therefore have some unique permissions to them. From the [documentation](http://when%20updating%20the%20passwordprofile%20property%2C%20the%20following%20scope%20is%20required:%20Directory.AccessAsUser.All./):

> When updating the `passwordProfile` property, the following scope is required: `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`.

The [Directory.AccessAsUser.All](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#directory-permissions) is a Delegated Permission that requires an Admin. In other words, it allows someone a Global Administrator to change other another user's `passwordProfile`.

If you're looking to allow the end user to change their password themselves, there is also a baked in `ChangePassword` method in the SDK:

```cs
await graphClient.Me.ChangePassword("current-pwd, "new-pwd").Request().PostAsync();
```

*Note: that this also requires that Admin Consent be granted for `DirectoryAccessAsUser.All` before a user can execute it)*

Keep in mind that `DirectoryAccessAsUser.All` is a "Delegated" rather than an "Application" permission scope. This means it is only supported by the [Authorization Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code) and [Implicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit) flows; it will not work for daemon/service scenarios using the [Client Credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds) flow.

If you consider the potential exploits that could be achieved by a non-interactive application having the ability to change user's passwords at will, the reason for this restriction is pretty clear.

Comment: Thank you for providing this valuable information. It make sense why this isn't possible via Graph API using Client Credentials.

Answer (score 6):

An easy solution we found out is to add the application principal to the "Helpdesk administrator" role.

1. Go to **Azure Active Directory**
2. On the left click on **Roles and administrators**
3. Search for the **Helpdesk administrator** role and click on it

[image]

4. Click on **Add assignments** and paste your application object id
5. Wait 5 minutes or so for azure to take the changes into account

[image]

Comment: `Password Administrator` might also be a good role choice as it provides less permission than `Helpdesk Administrator`. Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference).

Comment: Hello @BrentRobinson yes this is true, we found out there a couple of roles that have the necessary privileges so you can choose whichever looks better suited to your case.

Comment: This is the only solution when you want to update password with an application. Thxs

Answer (score 1):

For anyone arriving at this Q&A in 2021 - there is a password reset endpoint in Graph:

```
POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/authentication/passwordMethods/{id}/resetPassword
```

You will have to retrieve the id of the password authentication method first.

The permission needed for this operation is `UserAuthenticationMethod.ReadWrite.All` which *can* be granted as an Application type permission.

See the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/passwordauthenticationmethod-resetpassword

**Update**

Even though the permission can be granted as an Application type permission, the call will not succeed in Application Context.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/246207/34upn-from-claims-with-value-null-is-not-a-valid-u.html