# How to get authorization code to reset password using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: xamarin.forms, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to reset password for signed in user in Azure Ad b2c in xamarin forms application like this.

```
     private static async Task<string> AcquireTokenForApplicationAsync(string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{GlobalSettings.Tenant}");                
        ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult =
            await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
                "https://graph.microsoft.com",
                clientCred);
        string token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
        return token;
    }


    public async Task<User> ChangePasswordAsync(string oldPassword,string newPassword, string objectId)
    {
        try
        {
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
            new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
            {
                var token = await AcquireTokenForApplicationAsync(ResetPasswordClientId, ResetPasswordClientSecret);
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bearer Token: " + token);
            }));

            await graphClient.Me.ChangePassword(oldPassword, newPassword).Request().PostAsync();

            return new User();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error Calling the Graph API: \n" + ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

How to get authorization code to reset password? I have given scope to application while registration Directory.AccessAsUser.All.

[I had referred to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45982912/microsoft-graph-api-update-password-insufficient-privileges-to-complete-the), done everything as described except couldn't get authorization code or any other way to do it.

Comment: Please share correlation id and time stamp of the error message

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity After trial and error, I found this to work with
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc